# (103/1009) Evaluate The Legendre Symbol

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues

I am relatively new to Legendre symbols.

For the following problem, I feel that what I have is correct thus far:

(103/1009) -> (1009/103) -> (82/103) -> (2/103)(41/103)

103 is congruent to 3 (mod 4) and 1009 is congruent to 1 (mod 4), I flipped (103/1009) without negating it.

1009 is congruent to 82 (mod 103).

Since 82 is composite, I split it into two prime numbers.

(2/103)(41/103) -> (103/2)(103/41) -> (1/2)(21/41) -> (1/2)(3/41)(7/41)

103 is congruent to 1 (mod 2) 103 is congruent to 21 (mod 41)

(21/41) was split into (3/41)(7/41) since 21 is composite.

(1/2)(3/41)(7/41) -> (2/1)(41/3)(41/7) -> (1/1)(2/3)(6/7)

41 is congruent to 2 (mod 3) 41 is congruent to 6 (mod 7)

(1/1)(2/3)(6/7) -> (1/1)(2/3)(2/7)(3/7)

(6/7) became ((2/7)(3/7) since 6 is composite.

(1/1)(2/3)(2/7)(3/7) -> (1/1)(2/3)(7/2)(7/3) -> (1/1)(2/3)(1/2)(1/3)

7 is congruent to 1 (mod 2) 7 is congruent to 1 (mod 3)

2 is a quadratic non-residue of 3, so (2/3) evaluates to -1. 1 is a quadratic residue of 3, so (1/2) evaluates to 1. 1 is a quadratic residue of 3, so (1/3) evaluates to 1.

I am not sure what (1/1) evaluates to. Please help me understand this.

(1/1)(-1)(1)(1)

Please let me know if I am on the right track. Did I go too far in trying to solve this? If what I am doing is correct, where do I go from here? Thanks! (1/1)(-1)(1)(1)

I tried to reduce each symbol when possible by flipping when both the top and bottom numbers are prime.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Comment: Mobius inversion does not hold for $p=2$.  The value of $(2\mid p)$ is given by considering $p$ modulo $8$.

Comment: worth repeating:  for primes $p \equiv 1,-1 \pmod 8$   we have Legendre $(2|p) = 1.$  while for primes $q \equiv 3,-3 \pmod 8$   we have Legendre $(2|q) = -1.$

Comment: The other thing you could use:  for $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4,$  we have $(-1|p) = 1$  But for $q \equiv 3 \pmod 4,$  we have $(-1|q) = -1$  it could be $(82|103) = (-21|103) = (-1|103)(3|103)(7|103) $   for$-1 \cdot -(103|3) \cdot -(103|7)$  and so on....The way you did it, note $103 \equiv 7 \pmod 8$  so that $(2|103) = 1.$

Answer (score 1):

The [Legendre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol) $(\frac{a}{ p})$ is only defined when $p$ is prime, so $(\frac{1}{ 1})$ shouldn't arise.  $(\frac{1}p) = 1$ for any prime $p$, since $1 = 1^2$ is a square.

Comment: So then (1/2) simply becomes since 1 is a quadratic residue of 2 and the final answer would be (1)(-1)(1)(1)  = -1 right?

Comment: No, $\left(\frac{103}{1009}\right) = 1$.  Note that by quadratic reciprocity $\left( \frac{3}{7}\right) = - \left(\frac{7}{3}\right)$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. (3/7) became -(7/3) because both 3 and 7 are congruent to 3 (mod 4).

Comment: So (1)(-1)(2/7)(3/7) became (1)(-1)(7/2) -(7/3). This became (1)(-1)(1/2) -(1) = 1?

Comment: When you typed $1=1^2$ is prime, did you mean to type $1=1^2$ is a square?

Comment: @Robert Israel, please let me know if the following is the correct way to reach 1? (1)(-1)(2/7)(3/7) -> (1)(-1)(7/2) -(7/3) -> (1)(-1)(1/2) -(1) = 1